nested if statement is printing all the output lines
My code is printing all the output lines regardless of the data that is input.
This is for C++
Write a program that prompts the user to :
Enter the temperature
Using nested if and else statements, output the following:
If the temperature is less than 40: "it is cold"
If the temperature is greater than or equal to 40 and less then 60: "it is chilly"
If the temperature is greater than or equal to 40 and greater than or equal to 60 but less then 80: "it is nice"
If the temperature is greater than or equal to 40 and greater than or equal to 80: "it is hot"
Note: You may not use "else if" statements and you must use nested if statements.
Here is the code:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int temp;
    
    cout << "Enter the temperature" << endl;
    cin >> temp;
    if (temp < 40)
    {
      cout << "it is cold\n";
    }
    if (temp < 60) 
    {  
       cout << "it is chilly\n";
    }
    if (temp < 80)
    {
       cout << "it is nice\n";
    }
    else (temp > 80);
    {
      cout << "it is hot\n";
    }
    // Add your code here

    

    return 0;
}


Tangential, but those aren’t nested; they’re all at the same level. The last else stmt doesn’t seem right (or necessary, really).

Think about the logic. Your code asks if it's below 40. If that is true, then will it also be less than 60? That's what your code is doing.

As for how ... Well, it seems your teacher has just given a stupid assignment. There's not really such a thing as "else if" in c++ anyway: it is actually the same as } else { if (...) { } ... So, write the code using "else-if" then add in curly braces to get the "nested" nature.

What input did you give the program?  What output did you expect?  Why did you expect that output?

There's not really such a thing as "else if" in c++ anyway: it is actually the same as else { if (...) { } } ... So, write the code using "else-if" then add in curly braces to get the "nested" nature.
if (temp < 40) {
  cout << "it is cold\n";
} else {
   if (temp < 60) {  
       cout << "it is chilly\n";
   } else {
       if (temp < 80) {
           cout << "it is nice\n";
       } else {
           cout << "it is hot\n";
       }
   }
}

Now there's no "else-if"

Ah, sorry. I did not mean to blame you for something (funnily harmless) underhanded. What I mean is that this could be done without ever using one else - as demonstrated in the other existing answer and in at least one other way, not using a && either. Of course with even less sensible code.

@Yunnosch, no worries. As someone who teaches at a university, such arbitrary requirements drive me crazy. It's intentionally getting students to write bad code.

If you assignment is not to use else statement

Note: You may not use "else if" statements and you must use nested if statements.

Then I think, you can use && inside your if statements to avoid what's happening for you. (This is still not nested if, as nested if means, you have if statements inside other if statements)
Let's go through your current code and let's say the temp value is 20
if (temp < 40)
    {
      cout << "it is cold\n";
    }

This if statement evaluates to true, because the value of temp is less than 40, so the program print "it is cold\n"
if (temp < 60) 
    {  
       cout << "it is chilly\n";
    }

Then, right after the previous statement, you have another if statement, which will also evaluate to true for the value of 20 (as 20 is less than 60) and goes into the if block and prints "it is chilly"
The same will happen for the next two if statements.
Here is what you could do. The first if statement is fine, you could keep it the same, and for the second if statement, you can write it as following:
if (temp > 40 && temp < 60) 
{  
     cout << "it is chilly\n";
}

This way, when the value of temp is 20, this if statement will not evaluate to true (is 20 more than 40 and less than 60? No. That's why it doesn't evaluate to true), and won't go into the if block, hence, it will not print "it is chilly\n".
You can do the same with the rest.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int temp;

    cout << "Enter the temperature" << endl;
    cin >> temp;

    if (temp < 40)
    {
      cout << "it is cold\n";
    }
    if (temp >= 40 && temp < 60) 
    {  
       cout << "it is chilly\n";
    }
    if (temp >= 60 && temp < 80)
    {
       cout << "it is nice\n";
    }
    if (temp >= 80)
    {
      cout << "it is hot\n";
    }



    return 0;
}

Also notice that I've changed the last else statement to an if statement as it's not correct syntax to have a parenthesis after the else statement. And also removed the semicolon on the line where you have else

Those are not tested if statments
